# Dock issue on secondary screen after upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, wayland, bug-reporting, dock, 23.04

I just upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04, I have the Dock set to auto-hide, however on my secondary monitor when I hover over it, it does not stay up it flickers or just doesn't open, however if I click where an Icon should be it opens the software. I tried screen recording it but the screen recorder on ubuntu records it as being there.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/447175395331145758/1105620957202227331/Screencast_from_2023-05-09_23-22-27.webm - Screen recording

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/447175395331145758/1105621351169003590/20230509_232352.mp4 phone recording of what actually happens.

PC Specs:

- Intel i7 6700k
- Corsair CMW32GX4M2E3200C16 VENGEANCE RGB PRO 32GB (2x16GB)
- AMD 5700XT
- Corsair RMi Series RM850i
- Main monitor is 2560×1440
- Secondary monitor is 1680x1050

If there's anything else I can add to help please let me know, I'm still very new to Linux and Ubuntu

EDIT: It doesn't appear to happen when using Xorg

Comment: I have the exact same issue since about a week, maybe two, on 22.04.2 LTS, so it is not just 23.04

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, the dock is set on auto-hide and it flickers the same way on my secondary monitor.

I upgraded from 22.04 to 23.04, didn't had the problem before, so the issue was introduced with the new version of ubuntu.

I hope they fix this quikly as it's very annoying.